# Java constructor requires argument

Tags: java, constructor

my first day coding Java and I have issue I don't understand.

First class Dog, compiles no problem:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Dog {
    String name;
    public void Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void bark() {
        System.out.print(name + " barks: HAF\n");
    }

    public void getName() {
        System.out.print("The name of the dog is " + name + "\n");
    }
}
```

Second class MyDog (I want to run this):

```
import java.io.*;
public class MyDog {
    String ja;
    public MyDog() {
        ja = "abc";
    }
    // Question - is the method/constructor above needed?

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Dog pejsek = new Dog("Jeff");
        pejsek.getName();
        pejsek.bark();
    }
}
```

But I have following output when compiling MyDog:

```
MyDog.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Dog(java.lang.String)
location: class Dog
        Dog pejsek = new Dog("Jeff");
                     ^
1 error
```

I have googled and in general this should mean I don't have argument in constructor but to me it looks like there is one and I don't know what is wrong :-(

EDIT: I see this post recieved many negative ratings (-5 currently), can I ask you what is wrong with it? I know it is vary basic knowledge here but I spent 25 minutes looking for an answer and didn't find it so in the end i asked here...

Comment: you have to import `Dog` class into `MyDog` class and remove the `void` from the `Dog` constructor

Comment: `public void Dog(String name)` is not a constructor. remove the `void`

Comment: You don't need any `MyDog(...)` constructor as you never do a `new MyDog(..)`.

Comment: @Eran you are correct, thank you

Comment: @Edwin I tried without importing and it worked (it is in the same directory). Thank you anyway

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff thenk you for noticing the small question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor declaration is wrong. Constructors look like this:

```
public Dog(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

It does not have the `void` modifier.

The constructor declaration in the class `MyDog` is correct but it is not correct in `Dog`.